# Controller class using variable from other class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how to handle a situation where I have a MY_Controller, Backend_Controller and of course the Backend extends the MY and I have other controllers like Login and other smaller controllers that extend the Backend. My question is if you notice on the login controller it needs to be able to access a variable inside of the backend controller? How can I get that variable to be used in this case?

In the backend controller I have this:

```
<?php
if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Backend_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');

        $cms_template = $this->config->item('cms_template');

        $this->data['template'] = $cms_template;
    }
}
```

Here's the login controller:

```
<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends Backend_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }    

    public function index()
    {   
        $js_page_addons = '<script src="'.base_url().'assets/' .$cms_template. '/js/validation/login_form.js"></script>';

        $page_view = 'login_view';

        $this->data['js_page_addons'] = $js_page_addons;
        $this->data['page_view'] = $page_view;
        $this->load->view('cms/' . $cms_template . '/usermanagement/index_view', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because MY_ prefix's get loaded by Codeigniter by default, and non prefixed controllers don't you need to include reference to your backend_controller class like so:

> if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
>
> include_once(APPPATH . 'controllers/backend_controller.php');
>
> class Login extends Backend_Controller  {
>       public function _*construct()
>       {
>           parent::*_construct();
>       }
>
> ```
> public function index()
> {   
>     $js_page_addons = '<script src="'.base_url().'assets/' .$cms_template. '/js/validation/login_form.js"></script>';
>
>     $page_view = 'login_view';
>
>     $this->data['js_page_addons'] = $js_page_addons;
>     $this->data['page_view'] = $page_view;
>     $this->load->view('cms/' . $cms_template . '/usermanagement/index_view', $this->data);
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you need to access variable from Backend Controller to Login Controller, since you are extending the `Backend_Controller` in `Login_Controller`, you could do:
in **Backend_Controller**::

```
public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();  
   $this->some_backend_var = "some_value_here";
   //OR
   ci()->some_backend_var = $this->some_backend_var = "some_value_here";
}
```

and in login controller some function , you could get it using:

```
echo $this->some_backend_var; //shows "some_value_here"
```

Did you mean something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to `$cms_template`, you should be able to get to it via one of several ways. Assuming both the `$data` array and `$config` property are not `private`, try either

```
$cms_template = $this->config->item('cms_template');
```

or

```
$cms_template = $this->data['template'];
```

Also, you don't need a constructor if it only proxies to `parent::__construct()`

Comment: What did you mean by that last line?

Comment: @KevinSmith Your `Login` class has a redundant constructor. Removing it will produce the same result.